# Is Google checkout and Google Wallet API same?

Tags: google-checkout, android-pay

I have implemented plugin for google checout payments but now i see the notice on google developer documentation that google checout is no longer available from november instead they released Google Wallet.
My question is :
**Is Google checkout and Google Wallet API same or i will have to change the API for google wallet ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer from Google Developer.
I have contacted them and they told this are totally different from each other and they will released new API for wallet as soon as possible. :)

Answer (score 4):

Google Checkout has been retired and will be shut down on November 20, 2013. You will have to change your integration. The announcement below has more details and options for migrating your payment processing:

http://googlecommerce.blogspot.com/2013/05/an-update-to-google-checkout-for.html

Different new Google Wallet APIs (such as **Wallet Instant Buy** or **Wallet for digital goods**) are available that allow you to accept online payments for physical goods, digital goods or services. A list of the available APIs and documentation is at:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153930/google-wallet-instant-buy-versus-inapp) for a good explanation of the differences between the Instant Buy and digital goods APIs.

Answer (score 0):

They are obviously different - otherwise there would be no point in the transition but there **may**/*should* be a fair amount of overlap between the two APIs.  Some good places to start looking at the differences is [here](http://www.googblogs.com/android-developers/transitioning-to-google-wallet-merchant-center/) and via the Android Studio.